# WSS and Document Converters

Tags: sharepoint, wss

MOSS suports installing document converters on the server, is this also supported in WSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this page and see if it helps.

[Document Converter Services Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979484.aspx)